# How can I clear cookies using angular-cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, cookies

Using Angularjs  i am working on a mobile app where I need to clear the cookies after logout. The service I got to use is cookie authenticated, so after logout I need to clear them out.

For that I have tried traditional JS procedures to clear those cookies but didn't work.

After doing some more research on it I have added angular-cookies libary  and used ngCookies to got access of the [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) and [$cookieStore](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) in my scope. All the [examples](http://www.mograblog.com/2013/05/angularjs-cookies-example.html) or SO posts I got says how to add/edit/delete new cookie using `$cookies` and `$cookieStore`.

But I am not setting the cookies by myself, its been set dynamically like JSESSIONID,SMSESSION..so on (a big string). When I try `$cookieStore.get('JSESSIONID')` results undefined. 
AFAIK cookies are key value pairs, if yes then why I am getting undefined. (Am I wrong somewhere)

Is there anyway I can read all the cookies and reset/clear them using angular-cookies library.

Comment: When you say "the service I use", is that service yours, and is it hosted on the same domain? You cannot read or write cookies for a different domain.

Comment: As I said its a mobile app, means I am calling a web service that stores cookies info in device webkit memory. Can i clear that?

Comment: I'm not sure. On iOS, I'm pretty sure that if it's a different domain that is setting the cookie, both the standard Safari browser and `UIWebView`s will respect the rules that you can't access cookies for another domain. You may be able to delete the cookies you want using [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html).

Comment: For this issue i ended up with Cordova plugin to clear cookies out. Checking this post after a long time , thought the solution might help someone.. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will iterate through stored cookies and remove them dynamically.

```
    angular.forEach($cookies, function(value, key) {
        $cookieStore.remove(key);
    });
```